# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I noticed this in the database.yml for a newly generated Rails 3.1 project:

```
# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
```

What does this exactly mean? Does it mean even if I, say, run `rake routes`, it will erase and regenerate my test database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rake routes` is not the same as `rake`

When you run `rake`, you're telling rake that you're not specifying a task to run. By convention, Rails has set this to run your unit tests for you. So when you run `rake routes`, you have specified a task and it will not run unit tests.

Also: after you run a migration, go ahead and run:
`rake db:test:prepare`

Otherwise, your test DB won't know about your new migration.

Answer (score 0):

> When you do end up destroying your testing database (and it will happen, trust me), you can rebuild it from scratch according to the specs defined in the development database. You can do this by running rake db:test:prepare.

from [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-three-environments)

```
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
```

from `database.yml`

It means what you can lose your data in case you will use same database for `development` and `test` environments. 
`rake routes` doesn't affect the data in the database

Answer (score 0):

When you run tests in rails (with `rake test`), the first thing it does is re-create your test database. The default task when you run `rake` in a rails app is `test`, so `rake` with no arguments is the same as `rake test`.

When you run other rake tasks (like `rake routes`), it will not erase your database.